# \align File not found or blank pdf

Tags: align

Whenever I try using align in ams math the document simply disappears with the error message file not found (texmaker) and a blank space (texstudio). Why do my documents disappear whenever I try using \align

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should post a minimal working example displaying that behaviour.

Comment: Align is an environment, so `\align` is wrong in any case, plus requires the amsmath package. Besides that nobody knows, please post code that produces this problem